# Need the bootstrap class "embed-responsive-item" to work with the fabric canvas element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fabricjs

So I am using bootstrap's `embed-responsive` structure that involves a wrapper with `embed-responsive` class & an additional class for defining aspect ratio & the child element with `embed-responsive-item` class. The problem is that it works for `canvas`, but when I initialize it as a `fabric.Canvas` it breaks.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <canvas id="popupEditorCanvas" class="embed-responsive-item"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `canvas` is kind of a static DOM object that doesn't really go easy with `css` changes. It is better to have it at a fixed res, if you really need to maintain the aspect ratio. You can always make it dirty by reloading the page everytime someone trigger `window.resize`. It's upto You! For me, fixing resolution for the canvas was the option.